# Fragment issue login

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

As I am working with a fragment I can not use the expression

```
Intent mainLobby = new Intent (MainActivity.this, MainLobby.class);
```

I needed it to change activity after a login. How do I get around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As last answer but i do this:

```
Intent mainLobby = new Intent (getActivity().getApplicationContext(), MainLobby.class);
startActivity(mainLobby);
```

**Edit

Normally when you make an intent you have to include the Context from you are doing it, so for that reason, if i were you i include the getActivity.getApplicationContext() in the first parameter, as you know the second parameter of intent is the class where you want to go.

Regards**

Comment: This is the code of a LOGIN. is there any way to log in "the background" while advancing to the next activity?

Comment: Sure you can. Search if doent existen some cuestión, if not, make a new thread, but yes you can, it depends how you handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Intent mainLobby = new Intent (getActivity(), MainLobby.class);
startActivity(mainLobby);
```

In fragment we have to get the activity with which it is attached. We can not just use intent directly with the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Replace it with this:

```
Intent mainLobby = new Intent (getActivity(), MainLobby.class);
startActivity(mainLobby);
```

Use getActivity() method in fragments because fragments are not activities, so instead write that to get the activity that is attached to the fragment.